# resize wx.ListCtrl after creation

Tags: python, wxpython

so I have a listctrl created and added to sizer.

```
import wx
class myFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None)

        panel1=wx.Panel(self)
        self.mainSizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel1.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        self.button1=wx.Button(panel1, label='xxx')
        self.list1=wx.ListCtrl(panel1, size=(300,-1), style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_VRULES)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.button1, 0, wx.CENTER)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.list1, 1, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 20)
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)

    def onButton(self, pliki):
        self.list1.InsertColumn(0, 'col1')
        self.list1.InsertColumn(1, 'col2')
        self.list1.InsertColumn(2, 'col3')

        self.list1.SetColumnWidth(0, 150)
        self.list1.SetColumnWidth(1, 150)

        self.list1.SetSize( ( sum([self.list1.GetColumnWidth(i) for i in (0,1,2)])   , -1) )

x=wx.App()
y=myFrame().Show()
x.MainLoop()
```

then when button is pressed, data is propagated to the list and then I want to change the size of the columns (its calculated from the data inserted). but when I resize the window - the list's size returns to previous (declared while it was created). how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SetMinSize to tell the sizer that works with the list not to go below the given size.
I also called PostSizeEventToParent so the list gets recentered by its sizer at its new size.

```
import wx


class myFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None)

        panel1 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel1.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        self.button1 = wx.Button(panel1, label='xxx')
        self.list1 = wx.ListCtrl(panel1, size=(300, -1),
                                 style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_VRULES)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.button1, 0, wx.CENTER)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.list1, 1, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 20)
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)

    def onButton(self, pliki):
        self.list1.InsertColumn(0, 'col1')
        self.list1.InsertColumn(1, 'col2')
        self.list1.InsertColumn(2, 'col3')
        self.sizeColumns()

    def sizeColumns(self):
        self.list1.SetColumnWidth(0, 150)
        self.list1.SetColumnWidth(1, 150)
        size = (sum([self.list1.GetColumnWidth(i) for i in (0, 1, 2)]), -1)
        self.list1.SetSize(size)
        self.list1.SetMinSize(size)
        self.list1.PostSizeEventToParent()

x = wx.App()
y = myFrame().Show()
x.MainLoop()
```

P.S. You could actually remove the original SetSize call

Comment: SetMinSize works fine. ListCtrl has no attribute PostSizeEventToParent(), but that's not a problem now